# Java Unexpected Rounding of Double/Float

Tags: java, floating-point, double, rounding

Can anyone explain the following behavior? This method is supposed to scale the loaded picture so that it is as large as it can be within certain bounds without going over.

```
private final File imageFile;
private final ImageLoaderListener listener;
private final int idealWidth;
private final int idealHeight;
private final float idealRatio;

@Override
protected BufferedImage doInBackground() throws Exception {
    BufferedImage origImage;
    BufferedImage scaledImage;
    int origHeight;
    int origWidth;
    float imgRatio;

    // Load the image.
    try {
        origImage = ImageIO.read( imageFile );
        origHeight = origImage.getHeight();
        origWidth = origImage.getWidth();
        imgRatio = origWidth / origHeight;
        //imgRatio = 5/7;
    } catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( AppFrame.getAppFrame(),
                "Could not load the image.", "Error Loading Image",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
        return null;
    }

    // Scale the image
    double scaleFactor = (imgRatio >= idealRatio) ? idealWidth/origWidth
                                                  : idealHeight/origHeight;
    int scaledWidth = (int) Math.floor( scaleFactor * origWidth );
    int scaledHeight = (int) Math.floor( scaleFactor * origHeight );

    scaledImage = new BufferedImage( scaledWidth, scaledHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp( 
            at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC );
    scaledImage = scaleOp.filter(origImage, scaledImage);

    return scaledImage;
}
```

This is the unexpected result: All of the division is rounding without my telling it to. So if I run this with `idealWidth=1920` and `idealHeight=925`, the debug variable list shows `idealHeight = (float) 2.0`. Likewise, my test picture is 532x783, and `imgRatio = (float) 0.0`.  ScaleFactor is doing the same thing: the 532x783 image results in `ScaleFactor = (double) 1.0`

When I originally started to bugfix this, I had inadvertently declared the ratio variables (`idealRatio` and `imgRatio`) as `int`s. I saw this, changed them to doubles, and did a clean build, thinking it was fixed. Then I changed them to floats after doubles didn't work. Now I'm stumped. Why on earth would Java still be acting as if they were `int`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is standard Java (and most statically typed languages, thanks Daniel) behavior. What you are doing here is integer division which will always return an integer (same type as values in division operation) unless you take measures to prevent it. You could either make the variables into floats/doubles or cast one to a float/double to have the division expression return a float/double with standard rounding.

Comment: This is not just Java behavior, BTW.  It's true of virtually all programming languages that have static typing.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. Strange that I haven't seen this happen before; I must have been preventing it without knowing I was.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry if I made it seem sort of narrow. I didn't want to over reach and then have the inverse and have someone say "What about language X!?!?" lol.

Comment: Integer division in assembly produces an integer result on every CPU I know of.

Comment: Sounds reasonable since I imagine on any processor we would want to use that integer operations are piped through an integer optimized execution unit for that.

Comment: Actually, I can recall a few processors where integer division in particular was run through the FP unit, so that the complex division logic only needed to be in one place.  (Still produced an integer result, though.)

Comment: @HotLicks: It's not universal.  Pascal and VB.NET both use distinct tokens for fractional division and integer division.  I know that FORTRAN started out using the same token for both operations and lots of other languages including C copied that behavior, but that doesn't mean it was ever really a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Well, to start with, `5/7` is an integer expression.

(And so, apparently, are the other divisions, after a very brief review.)

Comment: Oh, oops. I should have taken that out before posting. I was trying to see if literal values made any difference.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference if literal or not.  Divide one integer by another and you get an integer result.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you can't just assign the result to a double and have Java perform double precision division, you need to cast each of your integer terms to doubles as follows:

```
int x=4;
int y=19;
double z = (double)x/(double)y;
```

Comment: why casting both of integers and not only one of them?

Comment: It's probably not strictly required, I think the compiler will perform double arithmetic if one or more of the arguments is a double. Casting both is just me being cautious.